# Getting error "missing } inserted. end{thebibliography}" in LaTex

Tags: latex, bibliography

I have no experience in using Latex. Using it to write my project. I am getting the error missing } inserted. end{thebibliography}. Below are the lines. It will be really helpful if anybody can tell what will be the correct format. Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{thebibliography}{8}
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL}

\bibitem[{.20(2016)}]{.2016b}
\enquote{{http://cs2016.statssa.gov.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/NT-30-06-2016-RELEASE-for-CS-2016-\_Statistical-releas\_1-July-2016.pdf}}
\newblock 2016.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{http://cs2016.statssa.gov.za}}

\bibitem[{.20(2020{\natexlab{a}})}]{.2020r}
\enquote{{https://www.statssa.gov.za/publications/P0318/P03182019.pdf}.}
\newblock 2020{\natexlab{a}}.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://www.statssa.gov.za/publications/P0318/P03182019.pdf}}

\bibitem[{.20(2020{\natexlab{b}})}]{.2020}
\enquote{{The Impact of COVID-19 on Food Security and Nutrition}} : 2--3.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://www.tralac.org/documents/resources/covid-19/3813-the-impact-of-covid-19-on-food-security-and-nutrition-un-policy-brief-june-2020/file.html}}

\bibitem[{Uni(2020)}]{UnitedNationsSustainableDevelopment.23072020}
\enquote{{Goal 2: Zero Hunger - United Nations Sustainable Development}.}
\newblock 23/07/2020.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/hunger/}}

\bibitem[{.30(2022)}]{.30052022b}
\enquote{{Impact of COVID-19 on people's livelihoods, their health and our food systems}}
\newblock 30/05/2022.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://www.who.int/news/item/13-10-2020-impact-of-covid-19-on-people's-livelihoods-their-health-and-our-food-systems}}

\bibitem[{.31(2022)}]{.31052022}
\enquote{{MoyaApp Questions}.}
\newblock 31/05/2022.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://moya.app/faqs/}}

\bibitem[{Hart et~al.(2022)Hart, Davids, Rule, Tirivanhu, and
  Mtyingizane}]{Hart.2022}
Hart, Tim~Gb, Davids, Yul~Derek, Rule, Stephen, Tirivanhu, Precious, and
  Mtyingizane, Samela.
\newblock \enquote{{The COVID-19 pandemic reveals an unprecedented rise in
  hunger: The South African Government was ill-prepared to meet the
  challenge}.}
\newblock \emph{{Scientific African}} 16: e01169.

\bibitem[{{van der Berg} et~al.(){van der Berg}, Patel, and
  Bridgman}]{vanderBerg.}
{van der Berg}, Servaas, Patel, Leila, and Bridgman, Grace.
\newblock
  \enquote{{Food-insecurity-in-South-Africa-Evidence-from-NIDS-CRAM-Wave-5}} :
  10--11.
\newline\urlprefix\url{\url{https://cramsurvey.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/13.-Van-der-Berg-S.-Patel-L-and-Bridgeman-G.-2021-Food-insecurity-in-South-Africa%E2%80%93-Evidence-from-NIDS-CRAM-Wave-5.pdf}}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Hmm... If it is possible, try to comment some bibitems with typing % at the begin of line  After it, You will be able to discover, which code is wrong 

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\url{\url{...}}` it should just be `\url{...}`.

That being said, you shouldn't use your redefinition for the `\url` macro. Better use the one provided by the `hyperref` or `url` package. URLs can contain tons of special characters which will likely break your redefinition at one point or another.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{8}
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
%\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL}

\bibitem[{.20(2016)}]{.2016b}
\enquote{{http://cs2016.statssa.gov.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/NT-30-06-2016-RELEASE-for-CS-2016-\_Statistical-releas\_1-July-2016.pdf}}
\newblock 2016.
\newline\urlprefix \url{http://cs2016.statssa.gov.za}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```